# Hiding the text of a TextBox control without using a PasswordBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, windows-phone-8.1, passwordbox

I am using a `TextBox` control for the user input in my Windows Phone 8.1 app.
**How can I hide the characters as user gives input**?

I am not using a `PasswordBox` because the defined `InputScope` is `"Number"` which is not possible in a `PasswordBox`.

While searching for a solution on the internet I found the only way by customizing the `TextBox` with the help of an `UserControl`.

**Is there any easier way to do this without creating any `UserControl`?**
Following is my code snippet:

*In XAML page:*

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding CardNo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    MaxLength="17"
    x:Name="CardNoTextBox"
    InputScope="Number"
    Margin="70,5"
    PlaceholderText="Enter Your Card Number"
    TextChanged="CardNoTextBox_TextChanged"
    BorderBrush="Gray"
    BorderThickness="2"
    FontSize="20"/>
```

*In code behind (xaml.cs):*

```
private void CardNoTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    if (IsTextAllowed(CardNoTextBox.Text))
    {
        if (CardNoTextBox.Text.Length == 5)
        {
            if (CardNoTextBox.Text[4] != ' ')
            {
                string text = CardNoTextBox.Text.Insert(4, " ");
                CardNoTextBox.Text = text;
                CardNoTextBox.Select(CardNoTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
            }
        }

        if (CardNoTextBox.Text.Length == 12)
        {
            if (CardNoTextBox.Text[11] != ' ')
            {
                string text = CardNoTextBox.Text.Insert(11, " ");
                CardNoTextBox.Text = text;
                CardNoTextBox.Select(CardNoTextBox.Text.Length, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        CardNoTextBox.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you catch the PreviewKeyDown event and replace the letter with a star?

Comment: I found no PreviewKeyDown event on my TextBox control. There is KeyDown event instead. I am new in this field. I am trying any possible solution but still with no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After spending hours in finding an easier way I got an amazing solution. Hope this would help others too.
**I simply added the following value to the `FontFamily` property of my `TextBox` control:**

```
FontFamily="ms-appx:///Assets/PassDot.ttf#PassDot"
```

And gave the size of font 35,

```
FontSize="35"
```

This works just fine for my project.

Comment: Not working for me. Furthermore, you should be worried about copy&paste and other stuff such as font availability and other stuff, when  you just change the font.

Comment: For me it is fine with just the font..I don't have issue with copy and paste..I guess definitely there will be a way around if any issues pop up in future. And actually it is a customed created font family which can be used for this kind of small aspect if someone wants to avoid the actual long process.

Comment: this doesn't work as `PassDot` isn't a default .NET font[at least it's not on my system or any of the systems of my colleagues]. It's also problematic because WPF won't tell you if the font isn't installed on a system. Meaning if you install the font on your system and deliver the software to customer X and he doesn't have the font, some default Windows font will be used and the password will be visible. Since `System.Windows.Media.FontFamily`'s constructor also doesn't throw an exception if it doesn't find a font you have no way of handling that situation.

Comment: You can bundle the font and load it as a resource, works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a custom TextBox, in which `Text` is *, but there is `hiddenText` that keeps the real string. Note that managing Caret position is not easy, because it changes due to some internal logic. Therefore, it is always at the end of the string. (Also note that you might need to handle some exceptions and bugs)

```
public class HiddenTextBox : TextBox
{ 
    internal string hiddenText { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
            addText(" ");
        else if (e.Key == Key.Back)
            removeText(true);
        else if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
            removeText(false);
        else if (e.Key == Key.Return)
            e.Handled = true;
        base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        addText(e.Text);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    void addText(string text)
    {
        hiddenText = hiddenText != null ? hiddenText.Insert(CaretIndex, text) : text;
        update();
    }
    void removeText(bool back)
    {
        if (hiddenText == null || hiddenText.Length == 0 || (back==false && CaretIndex == hiddenText.Length))
            return;
        if (back)
            hiddenText = hiddenText.Substring(0, CaretIndex - 1) + hiddenText.Substring(CaretIndex, hiddenText.Length - CaretIndex);
        else
            hiddenText = hiddenText.Substring(0, CaretIndex) + hiddenText.Substring(CaretIndex+1, hiddenText.Length - CaretIndex);
        update();
    }
    void update()
    {
        StringBuilder star = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var s in hiddenText)
        {
            star.Append("*");
        }
        Text = star.ToString();
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (hiddenText != null)
            CaretIndex += hiddenText.Length;
    }

}
```